# Creating automated equation list of symbols using glossary

Tags: glossaries, loops

I want to define a macro to add an automated symbol explanation under an equation. I have to use pre-defined glossary entries because the `\glsentrycurrent` does not allow to add new glossaries in the document. To add the automated legend I define the newcommand `\addLegeds` which should basically loop over all comma separated strings passed as an argument and check if they have been used befor. If all of them were used befor no legend should be added. The macro works exept that as soon as I use the `\gls` or `\glsdesc` macros, I get the following errors:

```
Argument of \@tempc has an extra }. \addLegends{test1,test2} 
File ended while scanning use of \@tempc.
Missing \endcsname inserted. \addLegends{test1,test2}
Paragraph ended before \@tempc was complete. \addLegends{test1,test2}
Undefined control sequence. \addLegends{test1,test2}
```

The following macro has been used:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifshowleg
\newcommand{\addLegends}[1]{%
    \showlegfalse
    \@for\@tempa:=#1\do{%
        \ifnumequal{\glsentrycurrcount{\@tempa}}{0}{\showlegtrue}{}}%
    \ifshowleg  %
        with: % 
        \begin{conditions} %
            \@for\@tempb:=#1\do{ %
                \ifnumequal{\glsentrycurrcount{\@tempb}}{0}{ %
                    \gls{\@tempb} & \glsdesc{\@tempb}\\ %
                }{}}%
        \end{conditions} %
     \else \fi %
}
\makeatother
```

And this is a reduced version of the latex document:

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\glsenableentrycount
% MACRO
    \newglossaryentry{test1}{name={test1},description={TEST1}}
    \newglossaryentry{test2}{name={test2},description={TEST2}}

\begin{document}
\addLegends{test1,test2}
\begin{end}
```

Does anybody know what is causing the error?

**UPDATE:**
By using

```
\csname gls{\@tempb} \endcsname  \csname glsdesc{\@tempb} \endcsname %
```

instead of:

```
\gls{\@tempb} & \glsdesc{\@tempb}\\
```

The code compiles, but doesn't show any output. Putting the `&` back in between doesn't compile. Has any ideas how to fix both problems?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this mini-glossary example](https://dickimaw-books.com/gallery/minigloss.shtml)?

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm looking for. Since I have many equations in my thesis, I want to show the symbol explanation only on the first occurance in each chapter. 

Since you are a quite experienced latex developer, you might can answer why the `\gls` and `\glsdesc` aren't working in my newcomand but `\glsentrycurrcount` does?

Comment: **EDIT:** I would like to use the extra command to avoid the extra length in the equations caused by the additional `\gls` commands.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without a complete MWE that provides your `conditions` environment, but I recommend using `\glsentrytext` and `\glsentrydesc` instead of `\gls` and `\glsdesc` in your list.

Comment: Just tried the  `\glsentrytext` and `\glsentrydesc`. They show the desired output, but but it seems that `\glsentrytext` doesn't increase the `\glsentrycurrent` and all symbols are shown for all equations, which is not intended. I could manually increase the counter if there is a way.

Comment: The counter is incremented with every use of `\glsunset` but that can cause problems in certain situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a definition of the `conditions` environment, but I'm guessing that it's a form of `tabular`. Since I don't know what it is, I've used `\begin{tabular}{ll}` in place of `\begin{conditions}` and `\end{tabular}` in place of `\end{conditions}`.

Loops are tricky within tabular contexts and it's often simpler to construct the contents and do the actual typesetting outside of the loop:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifshowleg
\newcommand{\addLegends}[1]{%
  \showlegfalse
  \def\leg@list{\begin{tabular}{ll}}%
  \@for\@tempa:=#1\do{%
    \ifnumequal{\glsentrycurrcount{\@tempa}}{0}%
    {\showlegtrue\eappto\leg@list{\noexpand\gls{\@tempa} 
      \noexpand& \noexpand\glsentrydesc{\@tempa}\noexpand\\}}{}%
  }%
  \appto\leg@list{\end{tabular}}%
  \ifshowleg    
      with: \leg@list
  \fi 
}
\makeatother

\glsenableentrycount
\newglossaryentry{test1}{name={test1},description={TEST1}}
\newglossaryentry{test2}{name={test2},description={TEST2}}

\begin{document}
\addLegends{test1,test2}
\end{document}
```

[image: with: test 1 TEST1 test2 TEST2]

The `\eappto` command provided by `etoolbox` (which is automatically loaded by `glossaries`) ensures that the label is expanded, but the awkward commands like `\gls` need to have their expansion prevented with `\noexpand`.

> ```
> \csname gls{\@tempb} \endcsname
> ```
>
> The code compiles, but doesn't show any output.

It won't show any output because it forms a command name that isn't defined. `\csname gls\endcsname` expands to `\gls` but `\csname gls{\@tempb}\endcsname` expands to a command with a name that includes literal braces surrounding the current value of `\@tempb`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you for your help and the thorough explanation!