# Automate equation variable description with glossaries-symbols

Tags: tables, lists, glossaries, etoolbox

I'm trying to automate the description tables of equations with the help of the `glossaries`-package. I already found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462658/creating-automated-equation-list-of-symbols-using-glossary) question, but on the one hand it didn't work for me, and on the other it seems quite complicated (in comparison to my current code).

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomain, symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

% \usepackage{showframe}
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={Alpha}, symbol={\ensuremath{\alpha}}, description={first symbol}}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{name={Beta}, symbol={\ensuremath{\beta}}, description={second symbol}}
\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={Gamma}, symbol={\ensuremath{\gamma}}, description={third symbol}}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\addVarDesc}[1]{
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\glsadd{##1}\makebox[0.5cm][r]{\glssymbol{##1}} ${}={}$ \glsname{##1}\\}
    \noindent with:\quad%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \docsvlist{#1}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}\par\medskip
}

\newcommand{\addVarDescTab}[1]{
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\glsadd{##1}\glssymbol{##1} & \glsname{##1}\\}
    \noindent with:\quad%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{${}={}$}l}
        \docsvlist{#1}
    \end{tabular}\par\medskip
}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries

\section{With multicols}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{equation}
        \alpha = \beta + \gamma
    \end{equation}
    \addVarDesc{alpha, beta, gamma}
    \blindtext[2]

\section{With tabular}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{equation}
        \alpha = \beta + \gamma
    \end{equation}
    \addVarDescTab{alpha, beta, gamma}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

With those results:

---

[image: The result with multicols]

---

[image: The result with a tabular environment]

---

As you can see, the multicol-variant is completely misplaced. Furthermore it is more difficult to align the entries equally. But with this version, I like the flexibility in the number of columns.

Whereas the tabular-version seems cleaner to me in the alignment of the items. However I waste more space horizontally.

Do you have any ideas how to improve the appearance? One thing I had in mind would be to split the tables in two tables side by side. But I don't know how to implement this with the `\docsvlist` command.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd keep the description inside the display in order to avoid excessive space between equation and description.

Also, we read from left to right (in English). It would be possible to obtain

```
alpha   gamma
beta
```

but I'm not inclined to do it.

I solve it with `expl3` that has many features that come very handy. First, I store the list in a sequence that can be mapped together with the index of items, so I can decide whether issue `\\` (at the end of a row) or `&` when adding items to a variable that stores the body for the next `tabular`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomain, symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newglossaryentry{alpha}{
  name={Alpha},
  symbol={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
  description={first symbol}
}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{
  name={Beta},
  symbol={\ensuremath{\beta}},
  description={second symbol}
}
\newglossaryentry{gamma}{
  name={Gamma},
  symbol={\ensuremath{\gamma}},
  description={third symbol}
}
\makeglossaries

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addVarDesc}{O{2}m}
 {% #1 = number of columns (default 2), #2 = list of keys
  \wulle_vardesc:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__wulle_vardesc_vars_seq
\tl_new:N \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wulle_vardesc:nn
 {
  \\\notag
  \begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__wulle_vardesc_vars_seq { #2 }
  \tl_clear:N \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__wulle_vardesc_vars_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl
     {
      \glsadd{##2}\makebox[0.5cm][r]{\glssymbol{##2}} ${}={}$ \glsname{##2}
     }
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { #1 } = 0 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl { \\ }
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl { & }
     }
   }
  with:~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}*{#1}{l}@{}} \l__wulle_vardesc_body_tl \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{gather}
\alpha = \beta + \gamma
\addVarDesc{alpha, beta, gamma}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{gather}
\alpha = \beta + \gamma
\addVarDesc[3]{alpha, beta, gamma}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{gather}
\alpha = \beta + \gamma
\addVarDesc[1]{alpha, beta, gamma}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[4][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was thinking of. I was always afraid of the expl3 syntax as it seems so... different. But once again I have to admit that it might probably be worth taking a look in the documentation.